# Add additional columns to Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I parse Spark dataframe using file paths but now I would like to add paths to the resulting dataframe along with time as a separate column too. Here is a current solution (pathToDF is a helper method):

```
val paths = pathsDF
  .orderBy($"time")
  .select($"path")
  .as[String]
  .collect()

if(paths.nonEmpty) {
  paths
    .grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
    .map(_.map(pathToDF).reduceLeft(_ union _))
} else {
  Seq.empty[DataFrame]
}
```

I am trying to do something like this but I am not sure how to add time column too using withColumn:

```
    val orderedPaths = pathsDF
      .orderBy($"time")
      .select($"path")
   //.select($"path", $"time") for both columns

    val paths = orderedPaths
      .as[String]
      .collect()

    if (paths.nonEmpty) {
      paths
        .grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
        .map(group => group.map(pathToDataDF).reduceLeft(_ union _)
          .withColumn("path", orderedPaths("path")))
    //.withColumn("time", orderedPaths("time") something like this
    } else {
      Seq.empty[DataFrame]
    }
```

What would be a better way to implement it?

Input DF:

```
time Long
path String
```

Current result:

```
resultDF schema
field1 Int
field2 String
....
fieldN String
```

Expected result:

```
resultDF schema
field1 Int
field2 String
....
path   String
time   Long
```

Comment: can you show schema of pathsDF ?? & Can you add what is your input & expected output ?? if possible

Comment: @Srinivas I have added expected result and input

Comment: join will work if both are dataframes ?

Comment: do you wanted to control files read from the path? I mean read only `x` files out of `y`, if not you can directly load all the files, no?

Comment: looks like you need to extend `pathToDataDF` to consume `time` as well as `path`, and use `lit` function to encode these literals as columns in resulted dataframe

Comment: also, this function might be helpful https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#input_file_name--

Comment: @Srinivas they don't have any common fields so I am not sure that join would work

Comment: @morsik Do you think there's a way to implement it without changing `pathToDataDF` method?

Comment: You can use row_number to create common fields in both datafram use that field as joining column .. will it work ??

Comment: Can you clarify this what is relation between inputdf and resultdf ?? And how are you creating inputdfband resultdf ??

Comment: @Srinivas basically, paths are only used from inputDF for retrieving data files and parsing them. And they are not used in resulting df because the data about path and time is not contained in files themselves

Comment: @Cassie, Based on my understanding of your requirement, I have added below solution, Please check & let me know if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code.

**1.** Change `grouped` to `par` function for parallel data load.

**2.** Change

```
// Below code will add same path for multiple files content.
paths.grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
     .map(group => group.map(pathToDataDF).reduceLeft(_ union _)
     .withColumn("path", orderedPaths("path")))
```

to

```
// Below code will add same path for same file content.
paths
.grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
.flatMap(group => {
    group.map(path => {
        pathToDataDF(path).withColumn("path", lit(path)) 
        }
    )
})
.reduceLeft(_ union _)
```

For example I have used both `par` & `grouped` to show you.

`Note` Ignore some of method like `pathToDataDF` I have tried to replicate your methods.

```
scala> val orderedPaths = Seq(("/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json","2020-05-29 01:30:00"),("/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json","2020-05-29 02:00:00"),("/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json","2020-05-29 03:00:00")).toDF("path","time")
orderedPaths: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [path: string, time: string]

scala> def pathToDataDF(path: String) = spark.read.format("json").load(path)
pathToDataDF: (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

//Sample File content I have taken.

scala> "cat /tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json".!
{"name":"Srinivas","age":29}

scala> "cat /tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json".!
{"name":"Ravi","age":20}

scala> "cat /tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json".!
{"name":"Raju","age":25}
```

**Using `par`**

```
scala> val paths = orderedPaths.orderBy($"time").select($"path").as[String].collect
paths: Array[String] = Array(/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json, /tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json, /tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json)

scala> val parDF = paths match {
        case p if !p.isEmpty => {
            p.par
            .map(path => { 
                pathToDataDF(path)
                .withColumn("path",lit(path))
            }).reduceLeft(_ union _)
        }
        case _ => spark.emptyDataFrame
    }
parDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> parDF.show(false)
+---+--------+------------------------------+
|age|name    |path                          |
+---+--------+------------------------------+
|29 |Srinivas|/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json|
|20 |Ravi    |/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json|
|25 |Raju    |/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json|
+---+--------+------------------------------+

// With time column.

scala> val paths = orderedPaths.orderBy($"time").select($"path",$"time").as[(String,String)].collect
paths: Array[(String, String)] = Array((/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json,2020-05-29 01:30:00), (/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json,2020-05-29 02:00:00), (/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json,2020-05-29 03:00:00))

scala> val parDF = paths match {
            case p if !p.isEmpty => {
                p.par
                .map(path => {
                    pathToDataDF(path._1)
                    .withColumn("path",lit(path._1))
                    .withColumn("time",lit(path._2))
                }).reduceLeft(_ union _)
            }
            case _ => spark.emptyDataFrame
        }

parDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> parDF.show(false)
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|age|name    |path                          |time               |
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|29 |Srinivas|/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json|2020-05-29 01:30:00|
|20 |Ravi    |/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json|2020-05-29 02:00:00|
|25 |Raju    |/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json|2020-05-29 03:00:00|
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Using `grouped`**

```
scala> val paths = orderedPaths.orderBy($"time").select($"path").as[String].collect
paths: Array[String] = Array(/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json, /tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json, /tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json)

scala> val groupedDF = paths match {
            case p if !p.isEmpty => {
                paths
                .grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
                .flatMap(group => {
                    group
                    .map(path => { 
                        pathToDataDF(path)
                        .withColumn("path", lit(path))
                    })
                }).reduceLeft(_ union _)
            }
            case _ => spark.emptyDataFrame
        }

groupedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> groupedDF.show(false)

+---+--------+------------------------------+
|age|name    |path                          |
+---+--------+------------------------------+
|29 |Srinivas|/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json|
|20 |Ravi    |/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json|
|25 |Raju    |/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json|
+---+--------+------------------------------+

// with time column.

scala> val paths = orderedPaths.orderBy($"time").select($"path",$"time").as[(String,String)].collect
paths: Array[(String, String)] = Array((/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json,2020-05-29 01:30:00), (/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json,2020-05-29 02:00:00), (/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json,2020-05-29 03:00:00))

scala> val groupedDF = paths match {
            case p if !p.isEmpty => {
                paths
                .grouped(groupsNum.getOrElse(paths.length))
                .flatMap(group => {
                    group
                    .map(path => {
                        pathToDataDF(path._1)
                        .withColumn("path",lit(path._1))
                        .withColumn("time",lit(path._2))
                    })
                }).reduceLeft(_ union _)
            }
            case _ => spark.emptyDataFrame
        }


groupedDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> groupedDF.show(false)
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|age|name    |path                          |time               |
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|29 |Srinivas|/tmp/data/foldera/foldera.json|2020-05-29 01:30:00|
|20 |Ravi    |/tmp/data/folderb/folderb.json|2020-05-29 02:00:00|
|25 |Raju    |/tmp/data/folderc/folderc.json|2020-05-29 03:00:00|
+---+--------+------------------------------+-------------------+
```